# Observer pattern Right for File Monitoring?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I am interested to know if the Observer Pattern is correct approach for implementing code to monitor log files and their changes?

I am currently using it, but there seems to be an anomaly that I can't quite explain. Basically, i create a Class called FileMonitor that has a timer that fires, that iterates a list of unique files looking for a changed "lastmodified date".

Upon finding it, a list of Listeners are iterated through to find the matching file, and it's 
fileChanged event is notified. It then begins to process the lines that were added in the file.

So to make my question more succinct:

1. Does the Observer Pattern fit what I am trying to do? (Currently
   I have one Listener per file)
2. Is there any possibility of 'concurrency issues' given that there is more than one File to
   monitor?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use Java 7, you can get the same behavior with [Apache IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

From the official documentation:

> FileAlterationObserver represents the state of files below a root
>   directory, checking the filesystem and notifying listeners of create,
>   change or delete events.

Here is how you can add listeners to define operations to be executed when such events happen.

> ```
>   File directory = new File(new File("."), "src");
>   FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(directory);
>   observer.addListener(...);
>   observer.addListener(...);
> ```

You will have to register the oberver(s) with a `FileAlterationMonitor`. Continuing from the same documentation:

```
  long interval = ...
  FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(interval);
  monitor.addObserver(observer);
  monitor.start();
  ...
  monitor.stop();
```

Where `interval` is the amount of time (in miliseconds) to wait between checks of the file system.

Look for package named `org.apache.commons.io.monitor` in the library.

Answer (score 5):

Java 7 has introduced `WatchService` which watches registered objects for changes and event.

> A Watchable object is registered with a watch service by invoking its
>   register method, returning a WatchKey to represent the registration.
>   When an event for an object is detected the key is signalled, and if
>   not currently signalled, it is queued to the watch service so that it
>   can be retrieved by consumers that invoke the poll or take methods to
>   retrieve keys and process events. Once the events have been processed
>   the consumer invokes the key's reset method to reset the key which
>   allows the key to be signalled and re-queued with further events.
>
> File systems may report events faster than they can be retrieved or
>   processed and an implementation may impose an unspecified limit on the
>   number of events that it may accumulate. Where an implementation
>   knowingly discards events then it arranges for the key's pollEvents
>   method to return an element with an event type of OVERFLOW. This event
>   can be used by the consumer as a trigger to re-examine the state of
>   the object.

Example -

```
Path myDir = Paths.get("D:/test");       

    try {
       WatchService watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
       myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE, 
       StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY);

       WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

       List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
       for (WatchEvent event : events) {
            if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                System.out.println("Created: " + event.context().toString());
            }
            if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                System.out.println("Delete: " + event.context().toString());
            }
            if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                System.out.println("Modify: " + event.context().toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Reference - [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

Comment: Thanks - but sadly I'm using Java 6 *forced too as our existing tech is all on 6*

Comment: you can use [Apache VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) what does exactly same with java 6.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the Observer Pattern fit what I am trying to do? (Currently I
>   have one Listener per file)

Yes it does.

> Is there any possibility of 'concurrency issues' given that there is
>   more than one File to monitor?

If you have multiple threads removing and adding listeners to a list backed up by an `ArrayList` you run the risk of `ConcurrentModificationException` . Use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead.

IIRC Effective java has an article containing a good example on the same.

Comment: +1 because a. correct and b. an answer to the question without adding another dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go for [NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)

and File Watcher services - [Watching File For Changes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)