# How to listen on file directory if file changed/added/deletd in java 6

Tags: java, filesystems, listener, filesystemwatcher

I googled for it and found java 7 has inbuilt support for it For example :- http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes

But did not get anywhere how to support it on java 6?

Some guys  at [Directory listener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941869/directory-listener-in-java) suggesetd for Jnotify, Apache VFS etc 
I can go for them provided java 6 does not provide something off the shelf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't possible in Java 6. Your best shot is to go for Apache VFS.

Comment: You can use the observer pattern to make the job. Maybe that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747063/observer-pattern-right-for-file-monitoring) may help